# SAP JCo Environment method isDestinationDataProviderRegistered() fails but does not throw an exception

Tags: java, jco

I have the following simple piece of code to register a DataProvider.
The line `Environment.isDestinationDataProviderRegistered()` fails.  The try-catch doesn't catch it.  The failure just kills the application.

Is there a way to find out what is actually happening? There is no exception. The application just fails.

I even wrote some loggers to test the static class.  All of the methods that started with Environment.in* print out the appropriate true/false response.  But, when I logger out all the Environment.is* methods (also booleans), then each one kills the application.

It surprises me that a simple boolean is*() method would fail.

My code:

```
try {
    destinationName = dbProps.getProperty(JCO_DESTINATION_NAME);

    createDestination(destinationName);

    if (! Environment.isDestinationDataProviderRegistered()) {
        Environment.registerDestinationDataProvider(new SAPJCOUtils());
    }

} catch (RuntimeException re) {
    re.printStackTrace();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What does "fail" mean exactly? SIGSEGV? Imploding CPU? ;-)

Comment: There must be some exception, but it falls out to the highest level 'finally' block.  But, there's no exception message i can trap.  If I use a JcoException in a catch clause, the editor tells me it's dead code because the method doesn't throw any exceptions.  It's weird.  It's a static method this is supposedly only returns true or false.  I am doing more troubleshooting, obviously, to understand.   I am using Maven to build the java application.

Comment: I see the problem.  I moved the "Evironment.isDestina..." line up to the Main, and got the 'can't rename the SAP sapjco3.jar file.  I am using Maven, I've hit this before, and.  So, that's my problem to solve.  Thank you @wegert.

Comment: So you are saying you get something like a NoClassDefFoundError? If you add a catch(Throwable t) to your code sample, you should be able to see what happens. BTW: if you managed to figure out the Maven problem by now, and it seems of interest to other users, you might want to post it here yourself and mark the question as "answered"?